# Sentiment Analysis with small Dataset

Tags: python, nlp

I want to do a multi class sentiment classification on some reviews that I have, in fact I want to label each review as "negative" , "more negative","less negative" and "positive", the problem is that I have a small dataset (that I created myself )  to train the algorithm. So I want some advice on which ML algorithm is appropriate to do a sentiment analysis with a small training set and why.